# Querying multiple schemas using EF

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I think this should be easy, but I cannot figure it out. 
I have an existing (legacy) database that I'm querying using EF, I have created a couple of POCO classes and as long as issue queries against the 'dbo' schema everything works great. The problem is I cannot issue queries against anyother schema, let say 'foo'. 
I tried overriding OnModelCreating and specifying the schema, but it doesn't seems to work...
Does anybody knows a  workaround for this?
For this particular case I only need querying capabilities (not insert,  update, etc..). 
If it is there anything that will works with queries only, it will be great too.
I'm using EF 5 targeting .NET 4.0
Any help will be apreciated. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, after a LOT of tries, I finally figured it out

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
//don't know why, but for some reason this doesnt work (from scott gu's blog)
//modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().ToTable("tblFoo", "bar");                        
//but this line of code does the trick ;)
 modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().ToTable("bar.tblFoo");
```

}

Answer (score 1):

the ToTable method is overloaded with the option to pass the Schema

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Poco>().ToTable("tabX","schemaY");
```

Thats interesting to know that "schema.table" works, but since the overload is there, may be better to use it.